# Can I /clone relative to entities, not the command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a map where you have to make a village from scratch, and I need help. I'm trying to make a `/clone` command happen relative to where a mob that's named house is, and I cant figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried the `/execute` command?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the `/execute` command.

The syntax you want is:

```
/execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command>
```

For example, to execute the clone command from an entity called "CloneMarker", you could do:

```
/execute @e[name=CloneMarker] ~ ~ ~ /clone ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~5 ~5 ~10 ~10 ~10
```

Comment: Note, that this is the old 1.12- syntax. For 1.13+ the syntax is `/execute at @e[name=house] run clone ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~5 ~5 ~10 ~10 ~10`.