# Copy player's armor and offhand items into a chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried to copy all items from a player's inventory into a chest in 1.16.
I have used this command for the hot bar and the 2 first rows in the inventory:

```
/data modify block 227 76 77 Items set from entity @a[tag=inbuild,limit=1] Inventory
```

For the 3rd row I have used these commands:

```
/summon minecraft:item ~ 69.00 85.46 {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},Age:5990s}
```

```
execute store success score itemdetect CopyInv run data modify entity @e[y=69.00,z=85.46,distance=0..1,type=item,limit=1,sort=nearest] Item set from entity @a[tag=inbuild,limit=1] Inventory[{Slot:35b}]
```

```
execute if score itemdetect CopyInv matches 1 run data modify block 227 76 79 Items[{Slot:8b}] merge from entity @e[y=69.00,z=85.46,distance=0..1,type=item,limit=1,sort=nearest] Item
```

It works, but now I need to do the same with the armor slots and the second hand but i cant get it to work :( Do I need to do something else to get the armor and the second hand to work, or am I just using the wrong slot IDs?  For the armor i use these ids:  `100`, `101`, `102` and `103`, and for the second hand i use this `-106`.   I can have missed something else when I did it, but I have done it 3 times and I never got it to work!

I'm playing in 1.16 (pre-release 5)

Comment: [This is a similar problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208561/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-entity-using-command-blocks) from a while ago, but luckily it sounds like it's at least possible now.  Have you considered using an armor stand for armor and off-hand item?

Answer (score 1):

## 1.17 Update

Since the release of 1.17, the previous answer is outdated. It still works, but you can achieve the same result much more quickly with `/item`, which is a dedicated command to copy items between slots in inventory or in container blocks:

```
item replace block ~ ~ ~ container.8 from entity @s weapon.offhand
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is that the `Slot` tag also gets copied, so the item gets copied into the chest and moved to slot 100, -106, etc., which makes it disappear again immediately.

Since there's nothing else with that many slots and you can't directly modify player data, you'll have to either copy `id`, `Count` and `tag` independently or go through something that doesn't care about the `Slot` tag, which can for example be an item entity (which automatically removes it, but that would place the item at slot #0 when copying it into the chest) or an arbitrary-NBT place like `storage`, where you can edit the slot number yourself.

The first method:

```
/data modify block ~ ~ ~ Items[{Slot:8b}] merge value {id:"stone",Count:1}
/data modify block ~ ~ ~ Items[{Slot:8b}].id set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:-106b}].id
/data modify block ~ ~ ~ Items[{Slot:8b}].Count set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:-106b}].Count
/data modify block ~ ~ ~ Items[{Slot:8b}].tag set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:-106b}].tag
```

The second method:

```
/data modify storage fabian:copy_help temp set from entity @s Inventory[{Slot:-106b}]
/data modify storage fabian:copy_help temp.Slot set value 8
/data modify block ~ ~ ~ Items append from storage fabian:copy_help temp
```

The parameter "`append`" puts the new entry at the end of the list, it can even become a 28th entry, but the list actually gets automatically reordered to be in the expected order and any item that was in that slot previously gets overwritten.